# vim getting the current value of vim foldmarker

Tags: vim

How do you find the value of vim variables that are set with one word commands

such as 
:set foldmarker={,}

I'm writing a simple custom function for foldtext() to set a custom one line summary of the folded region

it works great but looks funny when I open a documents with any fold marker other than what I've hard coded into the function

here is the function

```
set foldtext=GetCustomFoldText()
function GetCustomFoldText()
    let foldClose = '}'
    let foldTtl = v:foldend - v:foldstart
    return getline(v:foldstart) . ' (+) ' . foldTtl .  ' lines... ' . foldClose
endfunction
```

which makes this:

```
function myAwsomeFunction()
{
    // awsomeness here
    // awsomeness here
    // awsomeness here
}
```

folded becomes this:

```
function myAwsomeFunction()
{ (+) 5 lines... }
```

Which is great until I edit a document with a different foldmarker

I'm trying to determine foldClose dynamically from the foldmarker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `&` before the option name:

```
:let g:foo = &foldmarker
:echo g:foo
```

Answer (score 2):

:set all ; will print all vim settings

Answer (score 1):

```
:set foldmarker?
```

will show you current foldmarker
and you can get other settings current value using `:set xxxxx?`
xxxxx is the setting you want to know.